# Virtual MIDI on Android - possible?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, midi

Atm I use the [kshoji USB-MIDI-Driver](https://github.com/kshoji/USB-MIDI-Driver) to send MIDI data to a USB MIDI device. But I can not send MIDI data to another app on the same device. I'm looking for a Android solution similar to virtual MIDI ports on Linux, iOS/OS x or the [Windows loopBe1 driver](http://www.nerds.de/en/loopbe1.html).

Is it possible to write my data directly to the Input of a connected MIDI interface and other apps read this? (Not the best solution, because the user will need at least one hardware MIDI device).

Or is it possible to create an virtual USB driver and register it as MIDI device?

Or any other solution?

Comment: see [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

This USB MIDI driver talks directly to the USB controller.

Connecting multiple apps together would be possible only if the OS had some "MIDI port" abstraction (Android has not), or if all the apps are designed to work together with some other mechanism.

Comment: Is there any other mechanism standardised? I have read about google's [patch field](https://github.com/google/patchfield), but seems to be dead?