# Android, Java, Virtual/Loop back MIDI port/driver

Tags: java, android, qt, midi

Been banging my head against a brick wall on this...

I am looking to write a virtual midi driver - so android midi apps see a midi port to send to, I get to receive and pre-cook the messages before passing them on...

I can't find any starting point to get going(!).

Surely I just open a 'port' (using some library), the apps will see it, connect to it, send - and I get a call back for each message...

I am programming in Java/android stuido - but could use anything else if appropriate - I have used QT on Linux for anther part of the setup, but thought native Android would be best for an android driver(!).

**EDIT**

Seems android apps hit the metal for MIDI work (well as close to the metal as a USB driver is!), instead of using the Java MIDI libraries.

If so, my options would be:-
1) Write a USB driver that does the loopback - a 'virtual' device.
or
2) Attach a USB device and *physically* loop it back so my code can read the incomming.

I don't know where to start with 1 (any pointers?). 2 would be easier, but partly defeats the point... the code I want to write is to trap MIDI communication and push it out over WiFi. Needing a cable/add on is a bit naff - but would at least mean that the tablet isn't teathered to the main MIDI system...

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973531/virtual-midi-on-android-possible

Comment: Thanks Morrison - I have had a look, its a similar question, but has the wrong answer :) - it seem to say it can't be done, but with software anything is possible, just somethings are harder than others! :)

Comment: Might be useful to listen in on the audio section of this Android Developer Backstage Podcast: http://androidbackstage.blogspot.com/2015/01/episode-20-fonts-and-audio.html.  And checkout the links referenced on that page.

Comment: Cheers - have added the podcast to my regular list (I listen to loads).

Comment: I know this is old,  but I'm looking for something on Android that can patch a signal into a midi channel. I have a bluetooth midi controller that is not being recognized by music apps. The controller works fine with diagnostic apps that recognize ble midi, but most music apps are looking for some kind of usb midi.

Comment: @User27068 you could look at this library https://github.com/kshoji/BLE-MIDI-for-Android/wiki/Using-BLE-MIDI-Service - I switched the project onto raspberry pi, and used midings, but now use midish on there - I ssh onto the pi from android.